# Enter text in browser watir, ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, ruby-watir, selenium-ruby

I'm using watir to automate a task. After being logged in, i need to enter a text, my cursor is already on the message window so no need to locate the element, just need to type my text and send(:enter).
By the way, i can not locate the input bar.

So is there a command to tell watir to enter text without locating an element ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use `Browser#send_keys`, this should work:

```
browser.send_keys ['hello', :ENTER]
```

Comment: `browser.send_keys('hello', :enter)` worked ! Thanks a lot titusfortner :)